# Trigger a button click from a URL

Tags: web-scraping, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

We need to scrape [VEEC Website](https://www.veet.vic.gov.au/Public/PublicRegister/Search.aspx)  for the total number once a week.

As an example, for the week of 17/10/2016 - 23/10/2016 the [URL](https://www.veet.vic.gov.au/Public/PublicRegister/Search.aspx?CreatedFrom=17%2F10%2F2016&CreatedTo=23%2F10%2F2016) returns the number **Total 167,356** when the search button is clicked. We want this number to be stored in our database.

I'm using coldfusion to generate the weekly dates as params and have been passing them like the above [URL](https://www.veet.vic.gov.au/Public/PublicRegister/Search.aspx?CreatedFrom=17%2F10%2F2016&CreatedTo=23%2F10%2F2016). But I'm unable to find a query param so that the "Search" button click event is triggered.

I've tried like [this](https://www.veet.vic.gov.au/Public/PublicRegister/Search.aspx?CreatedFrom=17%2F10%2F2016&CreatedTo=23%2F10%2F2016&SearchButton=Search) & [this](https://www.veet.vic.gov.au/Public/PublicRegister/Search.aspx?CreatedFrom=17%2F10%2F2016&CreatedTo=23%2F10%2F2016&SearchButton#Click) but nothing seems to be working.

Any pointers?

Comment: Could you please give the details about, what kind of jar you have used to scrape an HTML? like jSoup, DocumentBuilder etc.. And could you give some sample code.

Comment: You need to use CFHTTP method="post". Just grab the URL using Firebug & copy the form fields into cfhttpparam type="Formfield"

Comment: @SaravanaKumar : I would be using Jsoup but right now I'm struggling to get the desired html from the URL.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like for every form submission, a CRSF token is added, which prevents malicious activity. To make matters worse for you, the CRSF token is changed for each form submission, not just for each user, which makes it virtually impossible to circumvent.

When I make a CFHTTP POST request to this form, I get HTML FileContent back, but there is no DB data within the results table cell placeholders. It seems to me that the form owner allows form submission from an HTTP request, but if the CRSF token cannot be validated, no DB data is returned.

It maybe worth asking the website owner, if there is any kind of REST API, that you can hook into...

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. REST API has always been our desired way of getting data but the website doesn't have an API hence trying to scrape the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a headless browser PhantomJS (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhantomJS) for this, here is a script that will save the total to a text file.

At command prompt, after you install PhantomJS, run `phantomjs.exe main.js`.

***main.js***

---

```
"use strict";

var firstLoad = true;

var url = 'https://www.veet.vic.gov.au/Public/PublicRegister/Search.aspx?CreatedFrom=17%2F10%2F2016&CreatedTo=23%2F10%2F2016';

var page = require("webpage").create();

page.viewportSize = {
    width: 1280,
    height: 800
};

page.onCallback = function (result) {
    var fs = require('fs');
    fs.write('veet.txt', result, 'w');
};

page.onLoadStarted = function () {
    console.log("page.onLoadStarted, firstLoad", firstLoad);
};

page.onLoadFinished = function () {

    console.log("page.onLoadFinished, firstLoad", firstLoad);

    if (firstLoad) {

        firstLoad = false;

        page.evaluate(function () {
            var event = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
            event.initEvent("click", true, true);
            document.querySelectorAll(".dx-vam")[3].dispatchEvent(event);
        });

    } else {

        page.evaluate(function () {
            var element = document.querySelectorAll('.dxgv')[130];
            window.callPhantom(element.textContent);
        });

        setTimeout(function () {
            page.render('veet.png');
            phantom.exit();
        }, 3000);

    }

};

page.open(url);
```

---

The script is not perfect, you can work on it if you're interested, but as is it will save the total to a file `veet.txt` and also save a screenshot `veet.png`.

Comment: Thanks, will give it a try.